# Tabs java scripts with HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tabs java scripts, but there is no default page.
I want to open the site to chose a page as a default tab.

Please help me

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#tabs a").on("click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
  var html = $(this).attr('href');
  var htmlurl = 'html/'+html;

   // update to the newest tab
   $("#tabs a").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");

   // set the new page content
   $("#content-wrap").hide().load(htmlurl, function(){
  $(this).fadeIn(400);
   });
 });
  });
```

Comment: Need to explain your issue in more detail. As it stands now it is not clear at all what you want to acheive

Comment: Some HTML for context would help

Answer (score 1):

Your problem doesn't seem to be clear to me, hovewer these lines didn't make sense.

```
// update to the newest tab
   $("#tabs a").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
```

In these lines , you refer to $("#tabs a") and remove the class and by using this statement , again you re adding the class.

Comment: makes perfect sense... removes from other elements that have that class and adds to the one that event occurred on